# Getting error while building in Jenkins

Tags: java, c, eclipse, maven, jenkins

I'm new to Jenkins and I'm trying to build, and i'm geting the following error in console. Please Help! I've resolved most of the problems that i could.

I'm followin tutorial: "http://www.guru99.com/maven-jenkins-with-selenium-complete-tutorial.html"

This Question is Related to this: "Steps to Install Jenkins and configure it to Run Maven with TestNg Selenium"

I've also resolved most of the error that occurred in the above tutorial and now I'm stuck on this

```
Started by timer
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\WebdriverTest
[WebdriverTest] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins5869105887311849511.bat

C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\WebdriverTest>D: -cp C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\lib*;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin org.testng.TestNG testng.xml 1>java 

D:\>exit 0 
Parsing POMs
Established TCP socket on 18731
[WebdriverTest] $ "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73/bin/java" -cp "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven33-agent-1.8.1.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\Maven\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\Maven/conf/logging" jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\tools\hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation\Maven" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-3.7.jar" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven33-interceptor-1.8.1.jar" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.8.1.jar" 18731
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73/bin/java" (in directory "C:\Users\Huzaifa\workspace\WebdriverTest"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:245)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:214)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:850)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:384)
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenProcessFactory.newProcess(AbstractMavenProcessFactory.java:278)
    at hudson.maven.ProcessCache.get(ProcessCache.java:236)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:798)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1735)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:544)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: What type of build are you doing, and what build step?  My first guess is you're using a script type that doesn't like having mixed slashes in your path to java. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73/bin/java`  You start with backslashes and switch to forward slashes, probably because part of that path is defined by a variable.

Comment: `Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified` - looks like pom cannot be found.

Comment: @Tuffwer can you tell where can i set that location? I can't find it.

Comment: @IvanPronin I checked and the location for the project is set as what i want it to be. that is: "C:\Users\Huzaifa\workspace\WebdriverTest\pom.xml"

Comment: That would be hard to say without knowing how you are executing that buildstep? Based on `[WebdriverTest] $ cmd /c call C:\Windows\TEMP\jenkins5869105887311849511.bat` I believe you are using an `Execute windows batch command` build step and have a batch script of some sort.  Can you share that step with us (by editing it into the question)?

Comment: @Tuffwer I've Updated the question please take a look.

Comment: What version of Jenkins are you using?  If it's still 1.X you should go to manage jenkins -> Configure system -> and check the path to your JDK on that page

Comment: @Tuffwer I'm using fully updated version that is 2.x

Comment: Go to Manage Jenkins as before but this time got to Global Tool Configuration instead of Configure System and either change or set the JDK path.